# matplotlib plot and then wait for raw input

Tags: python, matplotlib, png, python-imaging-library

I am trying to open a series of .png plots. I want to be able to view a plot on the screen and then get a prompt waiting for me to 'press enter'. On hitting enter, the next plot should be shown. I have seen many questions similar to this ([Matplotlib - Force plot display and then return to main code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149646/matplotlib-force-plot-display-and-then-return-to-main-code)) but when I do this I then have to manually click X on the top right-hand-side of the plot window to close it and only then does the code continue.

I am using python 2.7.8

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import string
import sys
import shutil

fig=plt.figure()

Viewingfile = sys.argv[1]


for test_file in open(Viewingfile, "r").readlines(): 

    fig.set_tight_layout(True)
    plt.ion()
    image=mpimg.imread(test_file + ".ps.png")
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    imgplot = plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()

    print test_file
    a = raw_input('Next plot?\n')
    if a == "1":
        print "Do something..I've skipped these details"
    plt.clf()

plt.close()
```

Comment: While I can't answer the question, would it be feasible to use an ipython notebook for this project instead of raw input?  That would still let you plot inline in real time.

Comment: I have never used ipython notebook. I have many images (thousands) to look through would you notebook be advisable for this?

Comment: IMO it makes more sense.  You can store the images that you want to keep (if any) in the notebook as you go.  Here's an example that shows plots/images in notebook:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/vanzaj/pyconsg2013-tut/blob/master/ipynb/04-Pandas-Scikits.ipynb

Protip: if the last line of a notebook cell is a plot/image call, the type of object (e.g. AxesSubplot) is printed out.  End your final call in the cell with a semicolon to suppress this.  EG:

plt.plot(x,y);

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With recent version of matplotlib, you can use the call [`plt.show(block=False)`](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show) to open the matplotlib window non-blocking.

Comment: When I change to the above line with `block=False`, the plots don't actually display anymore.

Comment: @Hephaestus , use plt.pause(0.1)