# Matplotlib plot a series of interactve plots one plot at a time

Tags: matplotlib, plot, python-3.4

I'm trying to plot a series of plots one plot at a time.  When a plot is displayed I want to be able to interact with it (i.e. zoom, pan, etc.) and wait until I'm done before the next plot is displayed.

I saw the post [matplotlib plot and then wait for raw input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164345/matplotlib-plot-and-then-wait-for-raw-input), but I couldn't get it to work.

I'm using Spyder and Python 3.4.

Below is the code snippet of what I'd like to do. However the plots seem to get blocked by the waiting for input.

```
for i in range(4):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot([x for x in range(100)],'x')
    plt.show(block=False)
    a=input('next plot')
```

Comment: If you are okay with closing the plot *before* showing the next (unclear in the question), just remove the input line and remove the `block=False` argument to show. `show` blocks by default until the plot is closed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for interactive plots in Python, you might want to take a look at the [Charts](https://github.com/arnoutaertgeerts/python-highcharts) library. It enables you to use the excellent [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com) javascript library to make beautiful and interactive plots. Highcharts uses the HTML `svg` tag so all your charts are actually vector images.

Some features:

- Vector plots which you can download in .png, .jpg and .svg formats so you will never run into resolution problems
- Interactive charts (zoom, slide, hover over points, ...)
- Usable in an IPython notebook
- Explore hundreds of data structures at the same time using the asynchronous plotting capabilities.

*Disclaimer: I'm the developer of the library*

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is resolved in the recent matplotlib v.2.0.0 release. At least it resolved this problem for me.