# Matplotlib - force display within a script

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is highly related to an earlier question by another person a couple of years ago: [Matplotlib - Force plot display and then return to main code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149646/matplotlib-force-plot-display-and-then-return-to-main-code)

I am using Canopy 1.5.5 on MacOSX 10.8.5, with matplotlib 1.4.3.

I will need to load data, look at it, press enter to approve and move to the next dataset (and do that a few thousand times, so it's kind of critical to get this functionality). Here is my MWE:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.figure() 
ind=np.arange(5)
for i in ind:
    plt.clf()
    plt.scatter(ind,ind+i) 
    plt.title('this is plot number %i' % i) 
    plt.show() 
    u=raw_input("Press any button")
```

The code seems to do everything EXCEPT actually showing me the plot. If I finish the script (or interrupt it), then I see the current figure.

I have tried everything from the previous answer: with and without interactive mode, with and without plt.show(block=False), every permutation of plt.draw and plt.show, and every backend on my available list.

This seems like a very basic functionality! Please tell me that this can be done. I find it weird that matplolib says here http://matplotlib.org/users/shell.html that "by default the drawing is deferred until the end of the script", but does not have suggestions on how to override the default. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Your example works for me (my backend is osx), although the figure window appears behind other windows at first. I needed to use alt-tab to raise it to the front.

Try starting your script with the `--matplotlib` option of IPython. You can select a backend or let it be auto-detected like so: `ipython --matplotlib auto yourscript.py`

Not sure if you now, but the `raw_input` function waits for you to press the return key, not just any key.

**Edit:**

About your last remark: [this section](http://matplotlib.org/users/shell.html#controlling-interactive-updating) explains how to force drawing before the end of the script. This can be done with the `draw` function. In interactive mode every pyplot command calls `draw` as well. Drawing in this context means rendering the figure by the backend.

Comment: YES! Worked from ipython. I'll continue messing with the Canopy prompt (still not working from there), but THANK YOU.