# Matplotlib: cycle through a list of plots, using a keystroke input

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to review a list of images in Matplotlib. However, I found that `plt.close()` does not close the current plot, and I need to manually do close the window. How can I resolve this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

for imgpath in imgpth_list:
    show_image(imgpath)
    image = Image.open(imgpath)
        title = imgpath.split("/")[-1]
        plt.imshow(image)
        plt.title(title)
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.show()
        _ = input("Press [enter] to continue.")
        plt.close()
```

Comment: Is your problem [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17149646/8881141)? Non-blocking behaviour of matplotlib is often fickle and depends on matplotlib version, backend, and OS.

Comment: oh, yes~ it works now thanks!